# mini-css-extract-plugin error when building react application

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass, react-bootstrap

```
chunk 2 [mini-css-extract-plugin]
Conflicting order. Following module has been added:
 * css ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-6-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--6-oneOf-6-3!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-6-4!./src/components/TabNav/TabNav.module.scss
despite it was not able to fulfill desired ordering with these modules:
 * css ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-6-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--6-oneOf-6-3!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-6-4!./src/components/SearchTableWrapper/SearchTableWrapper.module.scss
   - couldn't fulfill desired order of chunk group(s) , , , , , , 
 * css ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-6-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--6-oneOf-6-3!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-6-4!./src/components/DataTable/DataTable.module.scss
   - couldn't fulfill desired order of chunk group(s) 
   - while fulfilling desired order of chunk group(s) , , , , , ,

chunk 2 [mini-css-extract-plugin]
Conflicting order. Following module has been added:
 * css ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-6-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--6-oneOf-6-3!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-6-4!./src/components/SearchTableWrapper/SearchTableWrapper.module.scss
despite it was not able to fulfill desired ordering with these modules:
 * css ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-6-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--6-oneOf-6-3!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-6-4!./src/components/Filters/Filters.module.scss
   - couldn't fulfill desired order of chunk group(s) 
   - while fulfilling desired order of chunk group(s) , , , , , , 
 * css ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-6-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--6-oneOf-6-3!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-6-4!./src/components/DataTable/DataTable.module.scss
   - couldn't fulfill desired order of chunk group(s) 
   - while fulfilling desired order of chunk group(s) , , , , , ,

chunk 2 [mini-css-extract-plugin]
Conflicting order. Following module has been added:
 * css ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-6-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--6-oneOf-6-3!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-6-4!./src/components/Filters/Filters.module.scss
despite it was not able to fulfill desired ordering with these modules:
 * css ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-6-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--6-oneOf-6-3!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-6-4!./src/components/DataTable/DataTable.module.scss
   - couldn't fulfill desired order of chunk group(s) 
   - while fulfilling desired order of chunk group(s) , , , , , ,

chunk 3 [mini-css-extract-plugin]
Conflicting order. Following module has been added:
 * css ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-6-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--6-oneOf-6-3!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-6-4!./src/components/IconFormControl/IconFormControl.module.scss
despite it was not able to fulfill desired ordering with these modules:
 * css ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-6-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--6-oneOf-6-3!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-6-4!./src/components/DataTable/DataTable.module.scss
   - couldn't fulfill desired order of chunk group(s) , , , 
   - while fulfilling desired order of chunk group(s) ,

chunk 3 [mini-css-extract-plugin]
Conflicting order. Following module has been added:
 * css ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-6-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--6-oneOf-6-3!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-6-4!./src/components/DataTable/DataTable.module.scss
despite it was not able to fulfill desired ordering with these modules:
 * css ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-6-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--6-oneOf-6-3!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-6-4!./src/components/SearchTableWrapper/SearchTableWrapper.module.scss
   - couldn't fulfill desired order of chunk group(s) , 
   - while fulfilling desired order of chunk group(s) , , ,
```

I'm getting this css building warnings when I'm building react application with `yarn build`.
How can I remove this warning?
I'm using React, SCSS and React-bootstrap.

Hope someone give me a good idea to fix this.

Thanks!

Comment: Any update on this one?